# How to achieve ordering in telerik grid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, telerik-grid

I want to sort my telerik grid by its 3 columns such as by id, by pid, by perc. How to make order on telerik control?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the OrderBy method on the [Sortable](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-sorting.html) method argument:

```
<%= Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
        .Name("Grid")
        .Sortable(sorting => sorting
            .Enabled(true)
            .SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn)
            .OrderBy(sortOrder => 
                { 
                    sortOrder.Add(o => o.id);
                    sortOrder.Add(o => o.pid);
                    sortOrder.Add(o => o.perc);
                }))
%>
```

Comment: Do I need to write code in Controller for that? If yes then can you suggest me?

Comment: No, you can specify the default sorting in the view.